# @media queries not working with different viewport sizes

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I tried searching for questions on this site and I couldn't find any conclusions...so here goes....

My @media queries for my responsive web design doesn't appear to be working. When I resize the viewport, it still only has the styles on my stylesheet. I have to be missing something and It's becoming very frustrating to not be able to figure out why. I have the correct meta tag in my head, and I am pretty sure there aren't any syntax errors in my @media query code and I still can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code...and my media queries are located at the bottom of my CSS. Maybe thats my problem....hmm. Anywho.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="slick/slick.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <main id="mainContent" role="main">
 <article role="article">
 <section>
 <header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="single-item-rtl" dir="rtl">
        <div><img src="img/4.jpeg"></div>
        <div><img src="img/3.jpeg"></div>
        <div><img src="img/1.jpeg"></div>
        <div><img src="img/2.jpeg"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="logo"><img src="img/SJ_WHT.png" height="170px"    width="220x" align="center" /></div>
        <div id="text-top-carousel">
            <h1>a better way to book creative spaces</h1>
        </div>
</div>
</header>
</section>
<section class="container-fluid additional">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="info">
            <div class="icon icon1"></div>
                <h2>unique spaces <br> that inspire</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temor incididunt ut                                 labore etdolore magna aliqua</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="info">
            <div class="icon icon2"></div>
                <h2>hassle free <br> booking</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temor incididunt ut labore et                        dolore magna aliqua</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="info">
            <div class="icon icon3"></div>
                <h2>share your <br>creative space</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temor incididunt ut labore et                        dolore magna aliqua</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="motto">
    <h1>unleash your creativity</h1>
    <p>We focus on your artistic expression at Studio Junkey. We believe that your creative process is                              limited when the necessary resources are not available to execute your vision. <br></nr> We want to                          ensure that you find the studio space that has the tools you need to express yourself and your vision</p>
</div>
</section>
<section id="contactForm" class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="form col-md-6">
        <h3>Want to list a <br>studio space?</h3>
        <p>We are looking for more studios. <br>
           Send us your information<br> so we can connect.</p>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name">
                <select>
                    <option selected="selected">Type of Studio</option>
                    <option value="photography">Photography</option>
                    <option value="audio">Recording/Music/Audio</option>
                    <option value="painting">Drawing/Painting</option>
                    <option value="pottery">Pottery</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
            <input type="text" name="studioname" placeholder="Studio Name">
                <div class="shortForms">
                    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
                    <input type="submit" value= "Submit">
                 </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="form col-md-6">
        <h3>Need to rent a studio space?</h3>
        <p>We are working very hard to bring our vision to life. Studio Junkey will be ready soon...</p>
        <hr class="style-six" />
        <p>Enter your email address and we will notify you when we are ready to launch.</p>
            <div class="shortForms">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
<footer role="footer">
<h3>Questions? Feel free to<a href="#">contact us</a>.</h3>
    <div class="subFooter">
        <p class="copyright">©2015 Studio Junkey</p>
        <p class="termsPrivacy"><a href="#">Terms</a><a href="#">Privacy</a></p>
    </div>
</footer>
</article>
</main>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.single-item-rtl').slick({
        rtl: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 3000,
        arrows: false,
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: "Brandon Grotesque";
    src: url("fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_reg.otf") format("opentype");
}

html, body {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    font-family:"Brandon Grotesque";
}

#mainContent {
    background: white;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height:600px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
    padding:0;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding: inherit;
}

.row {
  margin: 0;
}

.single-item-rtl img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 600px;
}

#logo {
    position:relative;
    top:-595px;
    left:0em;
}

#text-top-carousel h1 {
    position:relative;
    top:-575px;
    left:0em;
    color:white;
    font-size:55px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#info {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin: 0px;
}

.info {
    height:auto;
    padding:20px 0;
    background:white;
    text-align: center;
    color:#333333;
}

.info .icon {
    width:150px;
    height:135px;
    padding:10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-position:15px 0px;
    background-size: 150px 150px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.info .icon1 {
    background-image:url("./img/icon%201.png);
}

.info .icon2 {
    background-image:url("./img/book122.png");
}

.info .icon3 {
    background-image:url("./img/icon%203.png");
}


.info h2 {
    padding:30px 48px 10px 48px;
    font-size: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    line-height: 1em;
}

.info p {
    padding:15px 50px 45px 50px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.motto {
    background-image:url("img/6.jpg");
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    clear: both;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    height: 600px;
}

.motto h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    padding-top: 90px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.motto p {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 15px 100px 90px 100px;
}

#contactForm {
    background: #EDEFED;
    margin-top:0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.form {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color:#333333;
}

.form h3 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 90px 185px 5px 185px;
}

.form p {
    font-size: 24px;
    padding:20px 150px;
    margin:0;
}

input[type="text"] {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  height:30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: none;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: block;
    background: #EDEFED;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 350px;
    height:30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    appearance: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: none;

}

select {
  -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 355px;
  height:30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: none;
}

.shortForms input {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 175px;
  height:30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: none;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.style-six {
    border: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width:150px;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}


.subFooter {
    padding: 0 100px;
}

.copyright {
    float: left;
}

.termsPrivacy {
    float: right;
}

footer a {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color:#333333;
    text-decoration: none;
}

footer a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #333333;
}

.additional {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width:758px) and (max-width:990px){
    .container{
        width:100%;
    }
    .info p{
        padding:15px 300px 45px 300px;
        margin: 0px;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: red;
    }

}
```

I've even tried to make obvious changes in the media query such as making the text color red, for example, and when I change the viewport size, it doesn't change. Any advice or help? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You have a typo in .info .icon2 on your CSS file, remove the quote. There could easily be an error in your CSS file such as this, or others.

Comment: Also`(min-width:758)` is missing a "px "

Comment: Nice catch guys! I have corrected these issues, but they still have not solved my problem unfortunately. I edited the code in the post.

Answer (score 2):

```
.info .icon2 {
    background-image:url(./img/book122.png");
}
```

This break your code Should be

```
.info .icon2 {
    background-image:url("./img/book122.png");
}
```

Comment: Nice catch! Thank you, but it unfortunately still did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />


@media all and (max-width: 990px) {
.container{
        width:100%;
    }
    .info p{
        padding:15px 300px 45px 300px;
        margin: 0px;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Media queries should be after all other css rules.

Comment: Really? I thought they just linked to your CSS stylesheet. So you put all @media queries in the head of your HTML document?

Comment: Oh no sorry you put the meta in the head of your html doc and the media query in the bottom of your css file.

Comment: you could also do this

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="slick/slick.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="slick/queries.css">

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently and discovered that the syntax of viewport initial scale was wrong. Using `"initial-scale=1.0"` broke all my media queries. Changing `"1.0"` to `"1"` fixed everything.